# How to Fill the Rectangle created by CGRect with Color

Tags: swift2, swift3

Below code wont paint the CGRect for Rect1,2,3

```
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

let Rect1 = CGRect(x:30, y:200, width:300, height: 50)
let Rect2 = CGRect(x:30, y:260, width:300, height: 50)
let Rect3 = CGRect(x:30, y:320, width:300, height: 50)

CGContextAddRect(context,Rect1)
CGContextAddRect(context,Rect2)
CGContextAddRect(context,Rect3)

CGContextsetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor)

CGContextFillRect(Context,Rect1)
CGContextFillRect(Context,Rect2)
CGContextFillRect(Context,Rect3)

let str1: NSString =" Hello"
let str2: NSString =" How are u?"
let str3: NSString =" See u"

let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 18.0)

let textcolor:UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

let attr = [NSFontAttributedName:font,
            NSForegroundColorAttributedName: textColor]

str1.drawInREct(Rect1, withAttributes: attr)
str2.drawInREct(Rect2, withAttributes: attr)
str3.drawInREct(Rect3, withAttributes: attr)

....
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is not swift 3.

Comment: How to make it work in Swift 2 or 3? Thanks

Comment: are you adding UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()  in drawRect of uiview otherwise it should return nil.